# Migration from TTStyledTextLabel

Tags: objective-c, xcode, three20

I am using TTStyledTextLabel from Three20 framework. I simply use it for text markup, like **bold text**. Now I should migrate from Three20.

What is the simplest way to implement TTStyledTextLabel functionality? May be there is TTStyledTextLabel equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel). It works like UILabel in iOS 6 but supports iOS 5 (maybe even iOS 4).

Comment: I tried to start TTTAttributedLabel example on Xcode 4.4.1, but had a compilation error (Use of undeclared identifier 'NSMutableParagraphStyle'). Seems NSMutableParagraphStyle is available from IOS 6 only. Are you sure it is compatible with IOS 5?

Comment: Mattt reply:Update your version of Xcode, and everything should work just fine. Either that, or use an older version of TTTAttributedLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the standard [`UILabel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html). It supports [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) starting from iOS 6.

Comment: Yes, NSAttributedString is good solution here. But I need to support IOS 5.